# How does Hegel develop the notion of freedom in his metaphysics?

Tags: political-philosophy, free-will, hegel

It is agreed by everyone that liberty is a good thing; and one cannot have enough of a good thing; thus unlimited liberty must be one of the most perfect of goods.

For in liberty unlimited one can express the fullness of being; being in its plenitude; but as Hegel noticed, pure being in this sense is hardly differentiated, though it is, from non-being.

But what notion of liberty can we attach to non-being? Possibly non-liberty; obedience in short.

Thus we consider obedience unlimited as the notion of liberty to attach to non-being.

But given Hegels equivocation between pure Being and pure Non-Being; one ought to regard as pure or unlimited liberty as equivocal to pure or unlimited obedience.

ie in a sense, pure liberty is a contradiction.

And as Becoming is the sublation of Being and non-Being; one might posit freedom as the sublation of pure liberty and pure obedience; as a kind of Becoming; the discovery and self-discovery of potential and it's actualisation.

Still, this is just freefall fancy footwork in a Rabbit-hole.

Question: How does Hegel himself develop the notion of freedom in his system of philosophy; that is, if he does?